# ALM Jenkins Configuration failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, alm

I currently face the problem that my HP ALM test automations are not running when executed with the HP Application Automation Tools. They are running fine when I trigger them from within HP ALM.
This is the output of the job:
Does anybody know what "Execution status: Error, Message: Access is denied" 
means. Is there maybe some permission configuration missing in HP ALM?

```
Building in workspace D:\Tools\Jenkins\workspace\Dani-JenkinsWithQC
[Dani-JenkinsWithQC] $ D:\Tools\Jenkins\workspace\Dani-JenkinsWithQC\HpToolsLauncher.exe -paramfile props20022014150821066.txt
"Started..."
Timeout is set to: 5
Run mode is set to: RUN_REMOTE
============================================================================
Starting test set execution
Test set name: JenkinsIntegartionTest, Test set id: 2457
"Number of tests in set: "2
Test 1: [1]Login will run on host: si0vm839
Test 2: [1]Logout will run on host: si0vm839
"Scheduler started at:15.09.2015 15:08:28
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15.09.2015 15:08:29 Running: [1]Login
15.09.2015 15:08:29 Running test: [1]Login, Test id: 938, Test instance id: 1412
Test: [1]Login, Id: 1412, Execution status: Running
Test: [1]Login, Id: 1412, Execution status: Error, Message: Access is denied
15.09.2015 15:08:33 Test complete: [1]Login
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15.09.2015 15:08:33 Running: [1]Logout
15.09.2015 04:15:08:33 Running test: [1]Logout, Test id: 939, Test instance id: 1413
Test: [1]Logout, Id: 1413, Execution status: Running
Test: [1]Logout, Id: 1413, Execution status: Error, Message: Access is denied
==============\nJob timed out!\n==============
================================================
Run status: Job failed, total tests: 2, succeeded: 0, failures: 0, errors: 2
Build step 'Execute HP tests from HP ALM' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

The user you trigger running from with in ALM and the user you configured in jenkins may not the same. [Check it here to see what user you're using for running from jenkins.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytwWD.png) Login to ALM, check which group does the user you configured in jenkins belong to. Maybe he is just a viewer or belongs to a group which doesn't have the permission of running test.

No idea about what the plugin version you're using. The latest release of jenkins plugin is recommended. [You can get it here.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HP+Application+Automation+Tools)